# Understanding a derivation of the SVD

Tags: svd

Here's an attempt to motivate the SVD.  Let $A \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$.  It's natural to ask, in what direction does $A$ have the most "impact".
In other words, for which unit vector $v$ is $\| A v \|_2$ the largest?
Denote this unit vector as $v_1$.  Let $\sigma_1 = \| A v_1 \|_2$, and define $u_1$ by $A v_1 = \sigma_1 u_1$.

Next, we would like to know in what direction orthogonal to $v_1$ does $A$ have the most "impact"?  In other words, for which unit vector $v \perp v_1$ is
$\| A v \|_2$ the largest?  Denote this unit vector as $v_2$.  Let $\sigma_2 = \| A v_2 \|_2$, and define $u_2$ by
$A v_2 = \sigma_2 u_2$.

**Question:** Are the vectors $u_1$ and $u_2$ guaranteed to be orthogonal?  If so, is there an easy proof for this fact, or a viewpoint that makes this obvious?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if $$\max_{\|v\|=1} \|A v\|$$ has $v_1$ as solution, then for every $v \perp v_1$ : $Av \perp A v_1$.

suppose  by contradiction that it exists $v_2 \perp v_1$ such that $Av_2 = c A v_1 + u_2$ where $c\ne 0$ and $u_2 \perp A v_1$. then $v_1$ can't be a maximiser of $\max_{\|v\|=1} \|A v\|$ :

let $w(\epsilon) = \sqrt{1-\epsilon^2} v_1 + \epsilon v_2$, hence $\|w(\epsilon)\| = 1$, and $$A w(\epsilon) =  \sqrt{1-\epsilon^2} A v_1 + \epsilon A v_2 = (\sqrt{1-\epsilon^2} + \epsilon c) A v_1 + \epsilon u_2$$

i.e. : 
$$\|A w(\epsilon)\|^2 = \underbrace{|\sqrt{1-\epsilon^2} + \epsilon c|^2}_{>\  1 \ \text{if } \ \epsilon \ \text{ is small  enough }} \|A v_1\|^2+ \epsilon^2 \|u_2\|^2 $$

this is enough to prove the SVD of matrices, since we can repeatedly compute $\max_{\|v\|=1} \|A_k v\|$ on $A_1 = A$ and then on $A_{k+1} = A_{k} - A_{k}v_{k} v_{k}^T$ where $v_{k}$ is the maximiser of the previous maximisation, and hence this is enough to prove the spectral theorem too.

Comment: Great answer! I was going to post something along these lines as well, but you said it much better.

Comment: @NickAlger : there was a mistake, no ? I replaced $A_k = A_{k-1} - v_{k-1} (A_{k-1}v_{k-1})^T$ by $A_k = A_{k-1} - A_{k-1}v_{k-1} v_{k-1}^T$

Comment: I didn't read that part in detail. It seems to me the core idea is everything before the last paragraph. Ie, if two vectors are not orthogonal, then you can always form a linear combination of them with weights that have sum-of-squares=1, such that the combination is larger than either one independently. Then you can apply the result recursively as you have done, or after presuming inductively that the first k singular vectors are orthogonal, use the result k times to show that the next vector is orthogonal to all of the previous ones, one at a time.

Comment: Thanks, this is interesting.  Can you explain how you and @NickAlger were able to recognize the "core idea" so easily?  In other words: is it a standard fact that if two vectors are not orthogonal then you can always find a linear combination of them, with weights that have sum-of-squares=1, such that the combination is larger than either one independently?  Is there a way to visualize that fact that makes it expected?  Is it a trick that you've seen used before in other proofs or problems?

Comment: @eternalGoldenBraid If you are familiar with the law of cosines in geometry, it can be seen as a special case of that, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines

Comment: @eternalGoldenBraid : and after you will probably study the bounded operators of Banach/Hilbert space (more or less the limit when $n \to \infty$ of the matrices on $\mathbb{R}^n$) and looking at $\max_{\|f\|=1} \|T f\|$ where $T$ is such an operator is what we do all the time (for example $T f(x) = x^2f(x)$ acting on functions $[-1,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ with norm $\|f\|^2 = \int_{-1}^1 |f(x)|^2 dx$, then $\max_{\|f\|=1} \|T f\| = 1$..)

Comment: @user1952009 Rather than introducing $A_{k+1}$, how about constructing vectors $v_i$ inductively like this: Given $v_1,\ldots, v_{k-1}$, let $v_k$ maximize $\| Av\|$ subject to the constraints that $\|v\| = 1$ and $v \perp v_i$ for $i = 1,\ldots, k-1$.  Claim :  if $v_{k+1} \perp v_i$ for $i = 1,\ldots, k$, then $A v_{k+1} \perp A v_i$ for $i = 1,\ldots, k$. Proof: $A v_{k+1} \perp A v_i$ for $i =1,\ldots,k-1$ follows by induction (details omitted).  If $A v_{k+1}$ is not orthogonal to $Av_k$, we can improve $v_k$ by perturbing it a bit in the direction $v_{k+1}$ (details omitted).

Comment: @eternalGoldenBraid : it is exactly the same, and for solving these minimization programs you will effectively compute the $A_k$ and minimize $\|A_k v\|$

Comment: @user1952009 Ah I see, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The shortcut that you might be inclined to take would be to try to prove that if $x,y$ are orthogonal then $Ax,Ay$ are orthogonal. But this is not the case, and in fact it is very far from being the case. It is not even the case when $A$ is symmetric positive definite, or even just diagonal with positive entries.

To proceed correctly you have to bring in the adjoint somehow. A way to do this is to note that $\| Ax \|^2_2 = \langle Ax,Ax \rangle = \langle x,A^T A x \rangle$ (the transpose is the adjoint for the Euclidean inner product). So the norm is maximized when you maximize this inner product. Cauchy-Schwarz tells us that it is maximized by the eigenvector of $A^T A$ with largest eigenvalue. This is your $v_1$, and its image is your $u_1$.

Now you take the orthogonal complement of $v_1$ when you go to define $v_2$. I don't see a way to conveniently work with this orthogonal complement without proving that it is invariant under $A^T A$, because otherwise $A^T A$ might not have any eigenvectors in there. (For example, with $B=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, this construction works to find the eigenvector $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$, but then the orthogonal complement of that is not invariant under $B$, and indeed $B$ doesn't have any other eigenvectors.) But once you've proven that, you've almost proven the spectral theorem, so you've gotten pretty far from the simple picture that you started with.

Comment: Just to check, do you agree with the proof (in the other answer) that if $x$ maximizes $\| A z \|$ subject to the constraint that $\| z \| = 1$, and $y$ is orthogonal to $x$, then $Ay$ is orthogonal to $Ax$?

Comment: @eternalGoldenBraid Yes, that's correct. This is ultimately because the span of $x$ is invariant under $A^T A$, which is why (as I said above) the maximization assumption is essential. The other answer uses a pretty clever geometric trick, rather than using the algebraic way of thinking about it that I had in mind.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my attempt at an intuitive explanation of the fact that $u_1$ and $u_2$ are guaranteed to be orthogonal, based on the answer given by @user1952009.
Throughout this answer, $\| \cdot \|$ will denote the $\ell_2$-norm.

Assume that $v_1$ is a maximizer of $\|Av\|$ subject to the constraint that $\|v\| = 1$.  Assume also that $v_2 \perp v_1$.

**Claim:** Under these assumptions, $A v_2 \perp A v_1$.

**Explanation:**
It's possible to look at this in a way that makes it intuitive or even "obvious".  If $Av_2$ were not orthogonal to $A v_1$, then it seems like we could *improve* $v_1$ by adding $\epsilon v_2$ to it, for a sufficiently tiny value of $\epsilon$.  When we perturb $v_1$ a tiny bit in the direction of $v_2$, then the norm of $v_1$ does not change (to first order, at least).  [A satellite in circular orbit moves locally in a straight line, and its distance from the center of the Earth is constant.]
However, we cannot say the same for the norm of $Av_1$, because $A v_1$ is perturbed in the direction of $A v_2$, and $A v_1$ and $A v_2$ **are not orthogonal**.  The growth in $\| A v_1 \|$ is **non-negligible**.

Again: when $v_1$ is perturbed in the direction $v_2$, the change in norm is negligible (so the norm is still $1$).  But, $A v_1$ is perturbed in the direction $A v_2$, and the change in norm is non-negligible (so the norm can increase).

Suppose you're standing 1 kilometer from the origin and you want to take a step in order to increase the magnitude of your displacement vector from the origin.  In which direction should you move?  Is it better to move in a direction orthogonal to your displacement vector, or parallel to it?  If you step in a direction orthogonal to your displacement vector, then the change in the magnitude of your displacement vector is negligible.  However, if you step in a direction parallel to your displacement vector, then the change in magnitude of your displacement vector is significant.

Finally, let's convert this intuition into a rigorous proof.
To get a rigorous proof, we have to face the fact that
$v_1 + \epsilon v_2$ does not actually have norm $1$ when $\epsilon \neq 0$,
even if $\epsilon$ is tiny.
We can fix this by taking our perturbed version of $v_1$ to be
\begin{equation}
\tag{$\spadesuit$} \tilde v(\epsilon) = \sqrt{1 - \epsilon^2} \, v_1 + \epsilon v_2.
\end{equation}
The vector $\tilde v(\epsilon)$ really does have norm $1$.

We are assuming (for a contradiction) that
$A v_2$ is not orthogonal to $A v_1$.  This implies
that $A v_2 = c A v_1 + w$, for some $c \neq 0$
and $w \perp A v_1$.
It follows that 
\begin{align}
\| A \tilde v(\epsilon) \|_2^2 &= \| (\sqrt{1 - \epsilon^2} + c \epsilon) A v_1 + \epsilon w \|^2 \\
&= (\underbrace{\sqrt{1 - \epsilon^2} + c \epsilon}_{>1 \text{ if }\epsilon \text{ is small enough}})^2 \| A v_1 \|^2 + \epsilon^2 \| w \|^2.
\end{align}
This shows that $v_1$ is not a true maximizer of $\| A v \|$ subject to the constraint $\| v\|_1$.  We have arrived at a contradiction.

The point of the intuitive discussion was to explain how we might think of perturbing $v_1$ as in equation ($\spadesuit$), and why we would expect this perturbation of $v_1$ to be an improvement on $v_1$.

Comment: Interesting, this actually bears a significant algebraic resemblance to the proof of Cauchy-Schwarz based on finding extrema of $f(t)=\langle x+ty,x+ty \rangle$. You are essentially saying that if $x$ is the maximizer and $y$ is orthogonal to $x$, then $f(t)=\| x \|^2+\Theta(t^2)$, but if $Ax$ were not orthogonal to $Ay$ then $g(t)=\| A(x+ty) \|^2$ would be $\| Ax \|^2 + \Theta(t)$. So $g$ would change so much faster than $f$ at $t=0$ that $g$ could still be made to grow even after you renormalize everything (because renormalization rescales everything by the growth rate of $f$, essentially).