# A textbook for SVD and PCA

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Could you please recommend a textbook with more or less detailed exposition of SVD and PCA (from algebraic perspective)

Comment: I attempted to give an intuitive explanation of the SVD here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1740483/225419  Qiaochu Yuan wrote a great blog post about the SVD here: https://qchu.wordpress.com/2017/03/13/singular-value-decomposition/

Comment: @ eternalGoldenBraid Thanks