# How to prove that 2 vectors in C(A) corresponding to orthogonal vectors in row-space of A are orthgonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orthogonality, svd

I was watching Singular Value Decomposition Lecture by Gilbert Strang. He takes two orthonormal vectors $v_1$, $v_2$. Let $\sigma_1$*$u_1$=A*$v_1$ and $\sigma_2$*$u_2$=A*$v_2$. He takes $u_1$ is orthogonal to $u_2$. How? How to prove this?

**Edit1**: Adding link to video lecture
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nx0lRBaXoz4 (Start from 3:30 mins)

Comment: You're assuming $\sigma_1\ne \sigma_2$ here. Consider $\langle Mv_1,u_2\rangle$, and use $Mv_1=\sigma_1 u_1$ and $M^*u_2 = \sigma_2 v_2$.

Comment: @TedShifrin, I didn't get it. Can you elaborate? Also 1 more thing. Does $M^T$$u_2$=$v_2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an explanation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1740483/516816) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1737839/516816). It explains that we choose $v_1$ such that $Av_1$ is maximum. Then we choose $v_2$ such that $v_2 \perp v_1$ and $Av_2$ is maximum. In that case, the above referred answers prove that 
$$Av_1 \perp Av_2$$
We choose 
$$u_1=Av_1/||Av_1||$$
$$u_2=Av_2/||Av_2||$$ Hence 
$$ u_1 \perp u_2$$

I guess Gilbert Strang omitted/missed this explanation in that lecture.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that the SVD is given by $ A = U \Sigma V ^ T $, hence
$ A ^ T A = ( U \Sigma V ^ T) (U \Sigma V ^ T)^T = U \Sigma ^ 2U ^T$. Namely, the columns of $U$ are the eigenvectors of $A ^ T A$, and as $A^TA$ is symmetric it is can be diagonilzed by an orthogonal matrix ($U$).

Comment: I ran into the problem while deriving SVD!

Comment: $u_1$ and $u_2$ are the first and the second column of $U$, which is orthogonal, hence by definition $u_1 ^ T u_2 = 0$. And the proof (that $U$ is orthogonal follows from my answer).

Comment: How do you say $U$ is orthogonal? In your answer, you've used SVD. But as I said before, Gilbert Strang uses the fact that $U$ is orthogonal to prove SVD. So, there should be another way to prove that $U$ is orthogonal without using SVD. I'm stuck there.