# Are linear transformations of orthogonal vectors Orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, orthogonality

Suppose there are 2 orthogonal vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ so $v_1^Tv_2=0$. Suppose we take linear transformations of the two vectors. Let $A$ be the transformation matrix. Let $u_1=Av_1; u_2=Av_2;$ Are $u_1$ are $u_2$ orthogonal? i.e. is $u_1^Tu_2=0$? How to prove it. I tried the following way, but I'm stuck.

$u_1^Tu_2=0$
$(Av_1)^T(Av_2)=0$
$v_1^TA^TAv_2=0$

I'm stuck here, unable to proceed further.

If the above equation is not true for any random vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$, is it true for any specific vectors? What if $v_1$ and $v_2$ are in $Row$ $space$ $of$ $A$?

Comment: This holds true if either $v_1$ or $v_2$ is an eigen vector of $A^TA$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true in general, but it will be true if $A^TA=\lambda\operatorname{Id}$, for some scalar $\lambda$. In particular, it is true if $A$ is an orthogonal matrix ($\iff A^TA=\operatorname{Id}$).

Comment: What if $v_1$ and $v_2$ are in row space of A? Is it true then?

Comment: @NagabhushanSN No, not even then.

Comment: thank you. I was watching Video Lecture by Gilbert Strang on Singular Value Decomposition. In that he takes two orthonormal vectors $v_1$, $v_2$ in row-space of A. Let $\sigma_1$*$u_1$=A*$v_1$ and $\sigma_2$*$u_2$=A*$v_2$. He takes $u_1$ is orthogonal to $u_2$. How?

Comment: @NagabhushanSN Post this as another question, with a link to the video.

Comment: here it is https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2777511/516816

Comment: amswer link: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2904688/516816

Answer (score 1):

Not it is not true in general, just consider $e_1=(1,0)$, $e_2=(0,1)$ and

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$$

It is true when $A^TA=k\,I$, indeed

$$\langle Ae_i,Ae_j \rangle=e_i^TA^TAe_j=ke_i^Te_j=\langle e_i,e_j \rangle=0$$